# How to modify a few methods of a package B when creating a new package A?

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package, lets call it package A. This package heavily depends on a package B (available via CRAN). However, on my local machine I made a few changes to the package B. These changes are necessary for the correct functioning of my A package.

The package A will be released. However, other users cannot install the modified B package, they only can install the original package B (via CRAN). **How can I ensure the few modifications to package B are available to other users?**

Ideally, I would only add the changed methods to my package A. When I do so however, these methods cannot find the other (non exported) functions from package B as these are not included in my package A. In this way I end up with adding all methods from the modified package B to my package A. This is undesirable as these will not be updated if the author of package B publishes an update. It feels like adding the complete package B (including modifications) to my package. Furthermore, it pollutes the new package A with unchanged methods from package B.

Comment: You need to rely on something called *masking*, where the same-named functions of package A are found *first* when A is loaded after package B. One caveat to this is that functions within B will still find its original functions (unchanged) first. (And by-the-way, it is incredibly difficult to change objects within a locked package environment, where unlocking it requires low-level code: https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369.)

Comment: Good examples of masking occur often when loading popular packages. `dplyr`, for instance, masks `stats::filter` with `dplyr::filter`; `data.table` and `dplyr` have many functions named in common, including `between`, `first`, and `last`, so whichever of the two is loaded *second* "wins". Another common problem is loading `plyr` and `dplyr` out of order, as their functions occasionally collide, as well.

Comment: I think the "ideal" fix for this would be for you to submit a pull-request (or similar mechanism) to the author of package B so that your suggestions become standard. That is not always trivial, depending on the complexity of your changes, as the maintainer now has to live with and maintain your ideas in perpetuity.

Comment: To whomever voted to close due to being *"about general computing hardware and software"*, that is clearly (to me) not the case: this is specifically about R's package namespace management ... specifically about how to code and/or maintain an R package so that other code is preempted or updated in-place. A question does not need to include actual R code (though typically it does) to be relevant on SO (so perhaps this is R-meta-programming). While I don't know that a *robust and general solution* can be found, I argue that that is an incorrect reason to close. Good luck, theRediut.

Comment: @r2evans, this question indeed relates to the namespace management. The masking strategy seems the way to go, but as far as I know, I cannot change the 'environment' of another package (and I am unsure if CRAN likes that). The ideal fix would indeed be that the other package adds the functionality, for now this is not realistic so a workaround must be found.

Comment: Yes, and I think the only workaround is masking. Or provide alternative (and not-same-named) functions where you clearly document to your users which to use. (But I'm interested to see if somebody else knows of a workaround. This is not the first time this type of question has been asked ... I'll look for similar questions later.)